# Query multiple SQL Server tables in parallel

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to know if there is way that I can run multiple `SELECT` queries or stored procedures in parallel? For a long time I was using one stored procedure which looks like below:

```
SELECT 1.......

SELECT 2 .......

SELECT 3 .......
```

Then I got `DataSet` with multiple DataTables.

Now I would like to run each SELECT statements parallel. I am not sure if I can do this using the same `SqlConnection` or if I have to use a separate connection for each query?

Do I have to use threads?

Comment: Does each select statement return the same columns or different columns?

Comment: Different. This SELECT statements can be stored procedures too.

Comment: @kumarch How this affect performance? What will be the best way to query multiple tables/view eg. for drop down lists in page? Will creating multiple connections improve the performance?

Comment: What about [Thread Pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as.aspx) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server will run all the 3 SELECTs in same session and in sequence as per you've done above.

If you want to execute all 3 SELECTs in parallel then you will have to invoke 3 threads (3 SPIDs, by creating separate connections) and execute by any script, like C# or VBA. But still its not guaranteed if they will run exactly parallel.